# reinterpret_cast from class pointer to long

Tags: c++, windows

I wrote a C++ application on Win64 with these lines:

```
Window* wnd = 0;
long l = reinterpret_cast<long> ( wnd );
```

The compiler displays the following error at the last line:

```
error: cast from 'window::Window*' to 'long int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

I use this value to put it into SetWindowLong (WindowsAPI) function.

I cannot understand this error. I am using MinGW-w64 (ruben build).

Comment: `long` is not big enough to store the `Window *` pointer value. Maybe you should use `std::intptr_t`, which is standard as of C++11... or, you know ask yourself why you're even trying to do this...

Comment: @oldrinb: Or even `std::uintptr_t` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I would have advised that if he was using `unsigned long` :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333890/reinterpret-cast-from-class-pointer-to-long#comment16555850_12333890).

The issue is that `sizeof(window::Window *)` is greater than `sizeof(long)`, meaning you can't effectively store the value of the pointer in `l`. This explains the error.

Now, what you should *really* want is actually to use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) instead.

> **Note** To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use **`SetWindowLongPtr`**. When compiling for 32-bit Windows, **`SetWindowLongPtr`** is defined as a call to the **`SetWindowLong`** function.

```
window::Window *wnd = ...;
HWND handle = ...;
int index = ...; /* e.g. GWLP_USERDATA */
LONG_PTR val = reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(wnd);
SetWindowLongPtr(handle, index, val);
```

Answer (score 1):

The message suggests the `sizeof(long)` on the architecture you are compiling for is less than the `sizeof(window::Window *)`. `long` is too small to store the value of a pointer on the architecture you are targeting.

Specifically, you appear to be targeting a 64-bit windows system architecture, where the LLP64 data model is used. In LLP64, a `long` is 32 bits, and a pointer is 64 bits.